# Open a text file, search for integer and then display text after a character

Tags: php

I have a multi-line text file that contains a number and url

```
59=folder/image.png
63=folder/image2.png
etc...
```

I want to search the file for "59" and then echo the url in img src

If the text file doesn't contain "59", I want to echo an alternative image

There's a problem because the png filename is also an integer

I have tried this with code that doesn't make sense, as pointed out by a user below.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to "search the file for 59", but surely actually you only want to search the beginning of the line. That would solve the issue with having numbers in the filename.

Your code so far doesn't make a lot of sense, it isn't searching for 59 at all, anywhere in the text.

This will do the job correctly:

```
$search_ID = "59"; //Note: this is now a string, so we can check its length, and match that in the file
$data = file_get_contents('text_file.txt'); //$contents was redundant, just start by calling it $data
$result = "";

if (substr($data, 0, strlen($search_ID)) == $search_ID)
{
    $result = substr($data, strpos($data, "=")+1); 
}
else
{
    $result = "something else"; //replace this with whatever alternative output you need
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb413cd66670001fe6e665b9e10b55285d1440b1

P.S. this code assumes the file only ever has one line. It wasn't quite clear from your question where there was the potential for it to have multiple lines in the same format, or not.

Comment: Thank you. The txt file will contain multiple lines. Each line will contain a different number, and URL.

Comment: ok. it would have been sensible to mention that (or show a multiline example) in the original question, as it changes the nature of the required code. You'll need to read the file line by line and process each line separately. You should be able to find out online already how to use PHP to read a text file line by line, so I'll leave that to you for now. If you get stuck then please update your question.

Comment: Thank you again. I've edited the question to include multiple lines. I've been experimenting with while loops and fgets but the page timed out.

Comment: Thanks. Please also update the question with the code you've tried which is causing you problems. P.s. how big is your test file - how many lines exactly?